# What does the -d flag do in tmux attach-session?

Tags: tmux

what does `-d` do for `tmux attach-session`? In the [manpages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tmux.1.html), we get this:

> If run from outside tmux, create a new client in the current terminal and attach it
> to target-session.  If used from inside, switch the current client.  **If -d is
> specified, any other clients attached to the session are detached.**  -r signifies the
> client is read-only (only keys bound to the detach-client or switch-client commands
> have any effect)

When I'm currently in a session and run `tmux new -d -s hello`, it works as expected. However, it doesn't seem to be the case when I run `tmux attach-session -d -t hello`.

```
$ tmux new -d -s hello
$ tmux attach-session -d -t hello
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
$ tmux ls
hello: 1 windows (created Fri Nov 24 00:49:57 2023)
world: 1 windows (created Fri Nov 24 00:49:50 2023) (attached)
```

For the record, I'm not trying to make a nested session - I want a command that will attach to the session if not attached, or switch to it if already attached to a different session.

Comment: r u currently being attached to "world"?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to create a new non-nested session using `tmux new -d -s hello` but I can't attach to it with `attach-session`. I can switch to it using `tmux switch -t hello` but then what's the point of `-d` in `tmux attach-session`?